# Membership.DeleteUser is not deleting all related rows of the user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

`Membership.DeleteUser()` manages to delete the userprofile of the user I am deleting. Why does it not also delete it's information stored in `webpages_membership`.

I am not using roles at this point in time so keep that in mind for your answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran a test and verified that [**SimpleMembershipProvider.DeleteUser**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.deleteuser%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) does not work as advertised. According to the documentation:

> This method deletes the entry in the membership account table (by default, **webpages_Membership**). If **deleteAllRelatedData** is true, all user data that is stored in the user table is also deleted.

But in my test I set **deleteAllRelatedData** to true and it just deleted the entry in the **UserProfile** table, leaving the entry in **webpages_membership** untouched.  Either a bug in the documentation or in the implementation of **SimpleMembership**.

But I did find a work around. First call [**SimpleMembershipProvider.DeleteAccount**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.deleteaccount%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). This will delete the entry in the **webpages_membership** table.  Then call **SimpleMembershipProvider.DeleteUser** to remove the entry in the **UserProfile** table.  Here is a snippet of the code I used for my test.

```
    var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
    var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

    if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
    {
        roles.CreateRole("Admin");
    }
    if (membership.GetUser("test", false) == null)
    {
        membership.CreateUserAndAccount("test", "test");
    }

    //Commented this out because you will get a foreign key 
    //error if you try to delete the user without removing the 
    //the mapping of the user to a role
    //if (!roles.GetRolesForUser("test").Contains("Admin"))
    //{
    //    roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "test" }, new[] { "admin" });
    //}

    //This will delete the user information from webpages_membership
    bool wasDeleted = membership.DeleteAccount("test");

    //This will delelet the user information form UserProfile
    wasDeleted = membership.DeleteUser("test", true);
```

As you can see from the comments this will not work if you are using roles and you have roles mapped to that user. You will need to remove those before you can remove the user. I know this is not an issue for zms6445, but I wanted to put this out there for people using roles.

Comment: How do you access the method DeleteAccount and DeleteUser. I attempted  your workaround and the only methods available to me in the SimpleMembershipProvider class is Equals and ReferenceEquals.

Comment: I added the code for my test in the Answer. Hopefully this will answer your question. If it does not provide code samples in your Question so I can assist.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, great answer.  I added to your answer code for deleting a user from roles.                                                                                   
foreach (var role in Roles.GetRolesForUser("test"))
    Roles.RemoveUserFromRole("test", role);                                                                                                                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439069/membership-deleteuserusername-true-not-removing-user-from-role/5439490#5439490