# Delete User with UserId in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a dropdownlist that contains values for all the UserId in the system.  When I click a button I want to delete the selected user by using their UserId.  Do I need to convert the UserId into a username before I can delete it?  Here is my code that I have so far:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser su = Membership.GetUser(ddlFullNames.SelectedValue.ToString());
    Membership.DeleteUser(su.UserName, true);
}
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5439069/558486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a GUI with user id and retrieve the user.

Do you can try this ?

```
//User id 
Guid userIdToDelete = new Guid("234hg-d23d23j-23d-23d2-2d23d23");
//Delete User with its id
Membership.DeleteUser(Membership.GetUser(userIdToDelete).UserName, true);
```

Comment: **WORKS!** Thanks! I just pulled in the userid from the selected item in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes the username is required in order to delete, but once you have the user object that's simple enough.

You could also use MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey to get the user, see [this link for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx)

The correct format is

```
Membership.DeleteUser("username");
```

or

```
Membership.DeleteUser(su.UserName, true);
```

or more simply

See [this link for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6b0zxdw.aspx)